# Convert symbolic links into corresponding target files

Tags: linux, unix, shell

I have several symlinks to other files in a directory. I want to convert these links into independent files.

Is there a command that does this?

Comment: are they hard or soft (symbolic) links?

Comment: They're soft links - editing the question.

Comment: I'm interested to know how to do this for hard links.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cp --remove-destination "$(readlink <symlink>)" <symlink>
```

Comment: That felt good!

Comment: Freebsd doesn't have `--remove-destionation` and using `-f` wasn't working too. So, needed to `orig = $(readlink <symlink>); rm <symlink>; cp $orig .`

Comment: This answer doesn't work PLURAL. It converts \*a* file. Not file**s**. I combined it a bit with other answers I found, to make the following command: `find ./ -type l -execdir bash -c 'cp --remove-destination "$(readlink "$0")" "$0"' {} \;`

Answer (score 1):

While Ignacio's is a good reply, I wanted to automate the process for every file that is a symlink in the current directory and subdirectories.

This does the trick:

find . -type l -exec cp \"{}\" \"{}.tmp$$\" \; -exec mv \"{}.tmp$$\" \"{}\" \;

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first way that comes to my mind would be to copy all of the links to new files then delete all of the links.

```
cp <link> <link>.new
rm <link>
```

Hopefully the files have some sort of common naming structure so you can use wildcarding and only run the commands once otherwise you might want to write a simple shell script

Comment: That's what I've been doing till now. I was hoping unix would have some command that does this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Mac OS X does not support the **--remove-destination** flag so I wrote a simple script to put in your /usr/bin directory:

```
FILE=$1
TEMP=$1".tmp"

mv $FILE $TEMP

if [ -e $TEMP ]
then
    cp "$(readlink $TEMP)" $FILE

    if [ -f $FILE ]
    then
        rm $TEMP
    else
        echo "unln failed."
    fi
fi
```

This one let's you use wildcards:

```
for FILE in "$@"
do
    TEMP=$FILE".tmp"

    if [ -h $FILE ]
    then
        mv $FILE $TEMP

        if [ -e $TEMP ]
        then
            cp "$(readlink $TEMP)" $FILE

            if [ -f $FILE ]
            then
                rm $TEMP
            else
                echo "unln failed for link: $FILE"
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```